# Resetting item positions to initial state in Swipeable

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, mobile

I swiped from right and left to delete and edit the data in the list with the 'Swipeable' component in React Native. But I want it to go back to its old positions immediately after pressing delete or edit after swiping right or left. How do I do this?

```
<GestureHandlerRootView>
      <Swipeable
        renderRightActions={() => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDelete(item.turkish)}>
            <View style={styles.deleteContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/delete.png')} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        renderLeftActions={() => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleEditModal(item.turkish)}>
            <View style={styles.editContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/edit.png')} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}

        
      >
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.textTurkish}>{item.turkish}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/ok.png')} />
          <Text style={styles.textRussian}>{item.russian}</Text>
        </View>
      </Swipeable>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
```

Here, I tried to save the positions with the state structure and set the same position for all items so that they would return to this position after the 'handleDelete' function, but unfortunately it was not successful. It remained the same.